# Por que hasNext() y hasNextLine() dicen que el archivo esta vacio si hay contenido?

Tags: java, scanner

Esta es parte de mi lista (es contenido de un archivo .txt):

```
1. Gladiator (El gladiador) (2000)  8,5 

  Rate

 El caballero oscuro
    
2. El caballero oscuro (2008)   9
    
  Rate

 Slumdog Millionaire    

3. Slumdog Millionaire (2008)   8   

  Rate

 Infiltrados
    
4. Infiltrados (2006)   8,5 

  Rate
```

Y este es mi código:

```java
File input = new File("movies.txt");
Scanner in = new Scanner(input);

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("MovieList.txt");
        
System.out.println(in.hasNext() + " " + in.hasNextLine());       
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String word = in.nextLine();        
    System.out.println(word);

    if (Character.isDigit(word.charAt(0)))
        out.println(word);
}

in.close();
out.close();
```

Como veis, el archivo incluye una lista de películas. Sin embargo, al copiarlas de internet, el formato en el que se han copiado es un poco erróneo. Mi objetivo es iterar a través de cada línea y si el primer carácter de la línea es un número, escribirlo en una nueva lista (generando el formato correcto).

Desafortunadamente `System.out.println(in.hasNext() + " " + in.hasNextLine());` salen como falsos por lo que el *loop* nunca se ejecuta.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que el archivo está donde dices? Yo probaría a poner el archivo en algún directorio conocido y poner la ruta completa, y no solo el nombre...

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un algoritmo para leer cualquier archivo de texto plano. Puedes adaptarlo a tus requerimientos

```
@Override
public Stream<String> leerAchivoLocal(String nombreArchivo) {
    Stream<String> lineas = null;
    Path ruta = null;

    try {

        lineas = Files.lines(Paths.get(ruta), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));


    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
      // if(lineas != null) lineas.close();
    }

    return lineas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos problemas pero la idea general va en la dirección correcta:

1 - Sin analizar el archivo no se puede asegurar que el primer caracter sea el número, puede haber un espacio en blanco o tab.

```
if ( Character.isDigit(word.charAt(0)) )
```

2 - Las lineas en blanco tiran un error cuando intentas obtener el charAt(0).

3 - Personalmente guardaría todo en una lista y luego lo escribiría en el archivo destino (opcional).

Dejo código ilustrativo:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    File f = new File("texto.txt");

    try {
        String word;
        int i = 0;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);

        while(s.hasNextLine()) {
            // leer la proxima linea
            word = s.nextLine();
            i++;
            // eliminar espacios en blanco u otros
            word = word.trim(); 

            // si no es vacia y el primer caracter es dígito
            if( word.length() > 0 && Character.isDigit(word.charAt(0))) {
                lista.add(word);
            }
        }

        // para evaluar los resultados (opcional)
        System.out.println("fin de lectura: lineas "+i+" digitos "+lista.size());
        s.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    // muestro la lista para ilustrar el resultato (opcional) 
    for(String e : lista) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    
    /* ESCRITURA */
    
    File dest = new File("pelis.txt");

    try {
        
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(dest);

        for(String e : lista) {
            pw.print(e+"\n"); // agregar salto de linea

        }

        pw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Para probar copie y pegé el ejemplo de archivo de la pregunta, puse los números iniciales en las lineas donde aparece el año y la nota (tiene lineas en blanco y tabulaciones).

**Nota:** *Los try-catch los generó automáticamente mi IDE (eclipse) se deben mejorar, o usar un try-with-resources.*